# How can I import module with custom context in jest?

Tags: javascript, jestjs

How can I import module with custom context in jest?
I've tried something like this:

Module.js

```html
(function(_scope) {
    console.log(_scope.variable);
})(this);
```

Test.js

```html
describe('test', () => {
    var module = require("Module.js");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i hope i understand you currectly

Module.js

```
exports.log = (scope) => { console.log(scope)};
```

Test.js

```
var module = require("./Module.js");

const dataToLog = "foo";
module.log(dataToLog);// foo
```

please press up arrow if you find that useful

Comment: This solution have problem, because I must modify Module.js. I find in "jest-runtime\build\index.js", line 521
<code> wrapper.call(localModule.exports, // module context</code>
but i can not understand how apply it

Comment: the problem is on your require
you should do it like require('./Module.js')
when you missing './' the require serching the module inside the node_modules and core modules

Comment: require successfully imported Module.js, but context inside Module.js is empty

Comment: if you meaning to pass the Test context send 'this' object either with the scope or try to bind(this) to the func from Test.js file

Comment: How to bind(this) to the func from Test.js file?